# Are ext2/3/4 USB Drives a critical threat to a Linux System?

Tags: ext4, usb-drive, vulnerability

I found this discussion [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/497106/) where those people seemed to decide weather ext filesystems should support the masquerading of the uid/gid similar to how a vfat/ntfs filesystems work when they are mounted on a Linux system. During that discussion, they seemed to decide that idea didn't have enough grounds.

My question is: Could an attacker place a setuid binary on an ext formatted USB Drive, insert it on another Linux system, run the binary (as an unprivileged user) and gain root access on that machine?

This seems like a trivial security exploit, and that patch would have allowed for a fix. Or am I missing something?

Comment: An attacker with physical access to the machine can already gain root much more easily without all that mucking about with setuid. Like booting a LiveUSB. Or booting into recovery mode.

Comment: @user535733 Those risks could be minimized by using fde. So the answer is a 'yes', then?

Comment: No, the answer is "It seems important to you, and perhaps you have a specific scenario in mind that it would be important for." In other words, an opinion-based question as currently written.

Comment: I don't think "Could an attacker" use this approach to gain root access is a matter of opinion...

Comment: Generally, external media like USB are mounted in FUSE, which will ignore setuid. If you discover a FUSE environment that permits setuid, please file a bug report, and add the Ubuntu Security Team to that bug report.

Comment: You could post it as an answer